# How to calculate in html table rows using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my table image that i have fetched from the another table 
in this table i am doing some calculation using javascript.When i tried to change the qty value,it should multiply with rate and show it in the total.
My problem when i change the value the both rows of the total shows same result.

[image]

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function calculate(id){ 
    var tot = 0;
    var qty = document.getElementsByClassName("qty");
    var rate = document.getElementsByClassName("rate");
    var total = document.getElementsByClassName("total");
for(var i = 0; i < qty.length; i++)
{
        tot = parseFloat(qty[i].value) * parseFloat(rate[i].value);
        $(".total").val(tot);
}

} 
</script>
```

My result i got is[image]

Comment: Well of course it is. `$(".total").val(tot);` modifies EVERY element of class total. Try `$(".total").eq(i).val(tot);`

Comment: @KhalilKhalil i have already tired it won't work

Comment: @KhalilKhalil `$(".total")[i].val(tot)` wont work as `$(".total")[i]` is getting the underlying DOM object therefore it doesnt have a `val()` method that is a jquery method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well of course it is. `$(".total").val(tot);` modifies EVERY element of class total. Try `$(".total").eq(i).val(tot);`

Note: this solution won't work if you have other `.total` elements on the page, outside of the table you're working on. You'll have to select the table first, `$('table#tableid .total').eq(i)...` to overcome that issue

Comment: i have another doubt can you help me

Comment: how to sum the value of total

Comment: before your loop, do `var total = 0;` inside your loop, do `total += tot;` After your loop, `total` will be all `tot` added up

Comment: it is not adding

Answer (score 1):

It does it cause you did not specify which which row specifically should be updated with the following line of code:

```
$(".total").val(tot);
```

What you do instead is updating values of all the fields within the class total.